Subgroups of finitely generated Abelian-by-$\mathbb Z^2$ group
Suppose $G$ is a finitely generated Abelian-by-$\mathbb Z^2$ group, i.e. it admits a short exact sequence $1 \to A \to G \to H \to 1$ where $A$ is abelian and $H = \mathbb Z^2$. Is it always the case that $G$ has a finitely generated subgroup $G'$ with a short exact sequence $1 \to A \to G' \to H'\to 1$ where $H'$ is a subgroup of $H$ that is isomphoric to $\mathbb Z$?
I don't think this is true in general.  The finitely generated metabelian groups with infinitely generated abelian subgroups I am aware of are Lamplighter groups and $BS(1,k)$ groups, I am not sure if I can construct a counterexample using these.
Any insight for such groups will be really appreciated. Thank you for reading.

For instance, take the wreath product $G =\mathbb Z_2 \wr \mathbb Z^2$, $G= A\rtimes H$, with $H=\mathbb Z^2$ and
$$
A=\bigoplus_{h\in H} \mathbb Z_2. 
$$
The group $G$ is finitely generated (as the wreath product of any two finitely generated groups). However, for any infinite index subgroup $H'< H$ the preimage of $H'$ in $G$ under the projection $G\to H$, cannot be finitely generated since the action of $H'$ on $H$ (via multiplication) has infinitely many orbits.
